# Reinitiate payment steps in sylius after unsuccessfull payment

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

Is there a clean way to give the user ability to retry payment if the attempt after placing order failed in Sylius 0.13?

I have frontend administration for users with list of their orders and I would like to add link to every unsuccessfully paid order that would forward user to `/payment/capture/<hash>` url like placing order.

Thanks.

Comment: The user would be [prompted to retry the payment method](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/5972864/6197547/3addc1b6-b3df-11e4-9099-528f79cac890.png) if it failed. Is there another step in the state flow that hasn't been accounted for?

Comment: Yes, for example when user didnt finish payment but wants to complete it later. I didnt find a clean way to make the payment possible without the order steps before as the order has already been placed.

Comment: Ah I see (I think ;), so you want customers to be able to resume from where they left of?

Comment: @AdamElsodaney Yes, exactly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem via regular controller which handles payment itself. We have order details on frontend where payment form is visible (if unpaid):

```
public function showAction($number)
{
    $order = $this->findOrderOr404($number);
    $form = $this->getPaymentFormIfOrderPayable($order);

    $view = $this
        ->view()
        ->setTemplate('SyliusWebBundle:Frontend/Account:Order/show.html.twig')
        ->setData(array(
                'order' => $order,
                'form' => $form,
            ))
    ;

    return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

New payment has always method as last one in database. After that it generates similar form like the one after completing order.

```
/**
 * @param OrderInterface $order
 * @return bool|FormInterface form if payable otherwise false
 */
protected function getPaymentFormIfOrderPayable(OrderInterface $order) {
    if($order->getState() === OrderInterface::STATE_PENDING) {
        /** @var PaymentInterface $paymentMethod */
        $paymentMethod = $order->getPayments()->last()->getMethod()->getGateway();
        switch ($paymentMethod) {
            case 'gpe':
                $form = $this->createGPEPaymentRequest($order);
                break;

            default:
                $form = false;
        }
    } else {
        $form = false;
    }

    return $form;
}
```

After payment, user is forwarded to another action that works like CaptureAction and PaymentStatusAction in Payum:

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @param string $number Order Id
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException
 * @throws AccessDeniedException
 */
public function payAction(Request $request, $number) {
    $order = $this->findOrderOr404($number);

    /** @var PaymentInterface $paymentMethod */
    $paymentMethod = $order->getPayments()->last()->getMethod()->getGateway();
    switch ($paymentMethod) {
        case 'gpe':
            $this->resolveGPEPaymentRequest($request, $order);
            break;

    $this->get('sylius.cart_provider')->abandonCart();
    $this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch('sylius.checkout.purchase.complete', new PurchaseCompleteEvent($order->getPayments()->last()));

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('sylius_account_order_show', array('number' => $order->getNumber())));
}
```